# Hibernate - join three times same table

Tags: hibernate, join, hql, jpql

I have this problem:

**two tables**:

```
tbl_suppliers
   id* (int), 
   name (string), 
   activity1 (int), 
   activity2 (int), 
   activity3 (int)

tbl_activity 
   id* (int), 
   description (string)
```

There is a kind of "**one-to-many**" relationship between the two tables: 
`tbl_activity` (one) --> `tbl_suppliers` (many) ; this means that every supplier can have all three ids filled for every activity or even no activity (no id).

I need to display the record of `tbl_suppliers` with columns `name`, `activity1`, `activity2`, `activity3`.

In SQL it's ok with this query:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, a1.description activitystring1, 
    a2.description activitystring2, a3.description activitystring3 
FROM tbl_suppliers s 
LEFT JOIN tbl_activity a1 ON (s.activity1=a1.id) 
LEFT JOIN tbl_activity a2 ON (s.activity2=a2.id) 
LEFT JOIN tbl_activity a3 ON (s.activity3=a3.id)
```

I can't do the same thing in HQL. Should I map three times "one-to-many" the activity field?

Comment: You must be having tbl_activity_id in tbl_suppliers. Right?

Comment: @RAS, he does have it, but names of the join columns are activity1, activity2, and activity3.

Answer (score 3):

Tables can be mapped as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_activity")
public class Activity {
    @Id private Integer id;

    private String description;
    //getters, setters, etc.
}

@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_suppliers")
public class Supplier {
    @Id private Integer id;

    private String name;

    @JoinColumn(name = "activity1")
    @ManyToOne private Activity activity1;

    @JoinColumn(name = "activity2")
    @ManyToOne private Activity activity2;

    @JoinColumn(name = "activity3")
    @ManyToOne private Activity activity3;
    //getters, setters, etc.
}
```

Original SQL query can be then expressed with following JPQL:

```
SELECT s.id, 
       s.name, 
       activity1.description, 
       activity2.description, 
       activity3.description
FROM Supplier s
  LEFT OUTER JOIN s.activity1 activity1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN s.activity2 activity2
  LEFT OUTER JOIN s.activity3 activity3
```

If you prefer more object oriented approach, you can simply query for Supplier and access descriptions via getActivity1.getDescription().

Comment: Thanx a lot !! It works if I use the query as above. If I simply select from Supplier it doesn't extract the 3 activities...should I set "lazy=false" in the "many-to-one" tags ? (I use xml files). I also thanx for the formatting of my post.